# Как отправлять сообщения пока нажата кнопка

Tags: java, android

Имею клиент на android. Сам клиент работает, при удерживании кнопки отсылает символ один раз. Вот только проблема в том, как сделать так, чтобы пока я удерживаю кнопку, отправлялся символ с определённой паузой между отправками.

```
    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
    b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b2);
    b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b3);
    b4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b4);

    client = new ClientThread();
    Thread thread = new Thread(client);
    thread.start();

    b1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                client.sendMessage("1");
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    b2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                client.sendMessage("22");
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    b3.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                client.sendMessage("333");
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    b4.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                client.sendMessage("4444");
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}


class ClientThread implements Runnable
{
    PrintWriter out;
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
            socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

            out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException e1)  {  e1.printStackTrace();  }
        catch (IOException e1) { e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void sendMessage(String str)
    {
        out.write(str);
        out.flush();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Вопрос не имеет к какой-либо IDE никакого отношения.

Comment: Есть [интересные решения](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284224/android-hold-button-to-repeat-action) на английском Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решение в лоб

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            if (timer != null) timer.cancel();
            timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    client.sendMessage("message");
                }
            }, 0, PERIOD);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            if (timer != null) {
                timer.cancel();
                timer = null;
            }
            break;
        default:
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, да таймер работает, но теперь ещё одна проблемка. 
Как запретить использование ACTION_MOVE? Потому как, при удерживании кнопки, если сдвинуть палец, отправка прерывается.
Можно конечно сбросить таймер и запустить на ACTION_MOVE, но мне совсем не нужен ACTION_MOVE.